# Get the biginteger number from String in java

Tags: java, sms, at-command, string-parsing, modem

I'm trying to parse messages I receive using AT+CMGL command.

My main interest is to get the 15 digit number from the message and store it in a table.

Here's an example of the data the I receive :

```
+CMGL: 0,"REC READ","+212664090320",,"22/09/14,10:58:33+04"
876011033120958
+CMGL: 0,"REC READ","+212664486654",,"22/09/14,11:47:33+04"
Ver:03.27.07_00 GPS:AXN_5.1.9 Hw:FMB920 Mod:13 IMEI:350444465129844 Init:2022-9-6 12:0 Uptime:1193 MAC:380A2986D9CB SPC:1(0) AXL:0 OBD:0 BL:1.10 BT:4
```

fyi, i get 8 different message format, I've just listed two here.

Comment: You mean the IMEI? You don't need to do calculations on it, so keep it as a string, don't try to parse it as a `BigInteger` (if that's what you meant with your title).

Comment: Well, if you know there is only 1 15-digit number you can use a regex like `([0-9]{15})` along with classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Comment: The IMEI is an identifier that happens to be numerical, but it doesn't make sense to do arithmetic operations on it (What would be the meaning of `myIMEI + 10` for example?). So leave it as a string and use it as a string only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Number storage mechanisms are for **numbers**, i.e. things you intend to do math on. It makes no sense to add 1 from an IMEI, or to subtract one IMEI from another. I doubt it's particularly sensible, therefore, to use `BigInteger` as storage format for an IMEI. `String` is fine.
2. To extract the IMEI from such input, regular expressions seem useful. I'd try `\bIMEI:(\d{15,16})\b`. That means: A 'word break', then `IMEI:`, then either 15 or 16 digits, then another word break. (IMEI are 15 or 16 digits currently). You can future proof matters by just using `\\d+`, which means '1 or more digits'. The parentheses also allow us to get that number out later. Then, make a matcher, find(), and ask for group(1):

```
private static final Pattern IMEI_FINDER = Pattern.compile("\\bIMEI:(\\d{15,16})\\b");

public String extractImei(String in) {
  Matcher m = IMEI_FINDER.matcher(in);
  if (m.find()) return m.group(1);
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("No IMEI found: " + in);
}
```

The above will return the first IMEI found in the input. You can repeatedly call `find()` if there are multiple `IMEI:` entries in there and you want them all; something like:

```
while (m.find()) imeiList.add(m.group(1));
```